# Fixing SoundManager.release ANR from trace.txt

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

I am getting the following ANRs while calling SoundPool.release(). This is not a consistent defect, but happening randomly. Hence reproducing it is kinda time consuming. There are 2 ways to fix it, AsyncTask or Thread. I don't think I can use a Handler here since release should not run on the UIThread.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x400281b8 self=0xd088
  | sysTid=3623 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006464
  | schedstat=( 22209377936 9072495824 21774 )
  at android.media.SoundPool.release(Native Method)
```

I have fixed it using Thread

```
public SoundManager() {
    releaseRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (releaseRunnable) {
                mSoundPool.release();
                mSoundPool = null;
            }
        }
    };
    releaseThread = new Thread(releaseRunnable);
}
public void release() {
    if (mSoundPool != null) {
        releaseThread.start();
    }
}
```

Am I doing it right ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Does your code work correctly?

Comment: Does anyone found solution to this issue?